# Angularjs: Unable to redirect to specific page

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an input form which is getting a redirection(errorredirection) url as part of button attribute and use a directive to read and set it in scope.

here is the input form:

```
  <input type="submit" id="submit-test" class="button blue" errorredirection="http://home.com/ExportControl.aspx" data-url="#ifSuccess" value="" redirect>
```

and the directive:

```
angular.module('xyz').directive("redirect", [ function() {
    return {
      restrict: "A",
      scope:false,
      link: function($scope, el, attributes, controllers) {
       $scope.errorredirection = attributes.errorredirection;
      }
    }
  }
]);
```

Now when I am calling this directive, the page is not getting loaded or it says "Directive name 'redirect' is invalid." . What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Have you included the xyz module into your main module? Is the directive loaded before you attempt to use it?

Comment: I have double checked, yes, the xyz module is the in there main module and directive is getting loaded before I can use it.